# using LD_LIBRARY_PATH goes segmentation fault

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm using Debian8.7 which is installed gcc4.9.2 via apt-get.

I built glibc2.24 and gcc6.3 with --prefix=/home/me/local, that looks finished correctly, but when using these adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/me/local/lib I got an error 'segmentation fault'.

I don't have any idea to solve this problem, could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use custom glibc just by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (e.g. your app will still use dynamic linker from old Glibc). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host) for details on how to achieve what you want. [Glibc testing wiki](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds) may also be of help.